# Migrating maven checkstyle to gradle

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I'm trying to migrate from maven to gradle, having a weird error with checkstyle.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'


jar {
    version = '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.3.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    checkstyle 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:6.10.1'
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
    testCompile('org.mockito:mockito-core')
    testCompile('nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:1.7.5')
}

test {
    maxParallelForks = 4
}
```

here's the error I'm getting

```
gradle build                                                                           slave-vi
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:checkstyleMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.
> Unable to create a Checker: unable to read /home/xenoterracide/IdeaProjects/entity-api/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml - unable to parse configuration stream - Property ${checkstyle.cache.file} has not been set

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.688 secs
```

How can I get gradle working with the latest version of checkstyle? worth noting my `checkstyle.xml` did work with maven checkstyle 6.10.1 and 6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in my configuration

```
    <property name="cacheFile" value="${checkstyle.cache.file}"/>
```

I don't remember adding it, maybe it's part of the sun configuration file, and just happens to get filled in by the maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using checkstyle plugin but you are not specifying any configuration for it.
Here you should add

```
   checkstyle {
  ignoreFailures = true
  configFile = file("/home/jenkins/scripts/checks.xml")
   }
```

and you should have your checkstyleing file in above mentioned location(You can change to whatever you want).

Here is the sample gradle file with checkstyle, PMD, findbugs, jacoco etc.
http://www.scmtechblog.net/2016/01/sample-gradle-file.html

You can add the information to your build.gradle to make use of it.